# 50 line automated application deployment solution

Tags: powershell, windows

I am running the following script, for some reason, I've edited this and broken it. It was patched together from 2 other scripts. The error I'm getting is:

> Remove-PSSession : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Session' because it is null.

For some reason, it's not picking up the computer names from the text file/CSV, I have one computer name in there as a demo/test.
Does anyone know what might be wrong?

This is the script:

```
Get-ADComputer -filter {Enabled -eq $True} -Properties cn -SearchBase "OU=Tablets,OU=DEPT,OU=Computer Accounts,DC=BUSINESS,DC=LOCAL" | select cn | Out-File c:\tablets.txt

$cred = Get-Credential BUSINESS\XY.admin
$computers = gc "C:\tablets.csv"
$TargetSession = $computers  

# This is the directory you want to copy to the computer (IE. c:\folder_to_be_copied)
$source = "c:\apps"

# On the destination computer, where do you want the folder to be copied?         
$dest = "c$"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    {
        Copy-Item $source -Destination \\$computer\$dest -Recurse
    }  
}

foreach ($computer in $TargetSession) {
    {
        #Creates a new remote PowerShell Session and script block - enter the code you want to execute remotely from this block 
        $Session = New-PSSession $computer -Credential $cred
        Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
            Start-Process "C:\apps\admin-deploy.msi" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait
            #Start-Sleep -s 20;
            #Start-Process ""
        }
    }
}
# Clean Up
Remove-PSSession -Session $Session
```

Comment: Please format your code, hard to help you if it's hard to read

Comment: Because your loops have too many `{}`. Each loop just generates a scriptblock out to the pipeline, it doesn't run anything. Compare `foreach ($i in 1..5) { $i }` and `foreach ($i in 1..5) { { $i } }`. And your remove-pssession should be inside the loop where it's created, after the invoke-command finishes.

Comment: What is it with these pointless nested scriptblocks? Is that a new fad or something?

Comment: Please do not move the target. The problem from your edit has nothing to do with this question, so please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the file you created is `c:\tablets.txt` but you are importing `c:\tablets.csv` hence it will be empty unless you change `$computers` to the following:

```
$computers = gc "C:\tablets.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `Remove-PSSession` inside the loop to dispose of each session individually.

```
foreach ($computer in $TargetSession)
{
    {
        #Creates a new remote PowerShell Session and script block - enter the code you want to execute remotely from this block 
        $Session = New-PSSession $computer -Credential $cred
        Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
            Start-Process “C:\apps\admin-deploy.msi” -ArgumentList “/qn” -Wait
            #Start-Sleep -s 20;
            #Start-Process ""
        } 
        Remove-PSSession -Session $Session # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
}
```